# Refresh Auth user data after update

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm displaying the name of the loggedin user in the header with `$this->Auth->user('name')`.

The issue is, when I update the name of the user how can I refresh this value at `$this->Auth->user()` because after I just updated the old name still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using stateless authentication, the data is stored and retrieved from the session, so you just need to update it there.

For example

```
$this->Auth->session->write($this->Auth->sessionKey . '.name', $newName);
```

Or maybe set the complete modified user data in case applicable (note that this will renew the session)

```
$this->Auth->setUser($updatedUserData);
```

See also **[API > Controller > Component > AuthComponent::_setUser()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Controller.Component.AuthComponent.html#_setUser)**

Comment: @DanielFaria No, an array, see **http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Controller.Component.AuthComponent.html#_setUser**

Comment: cool.. if I save like this `$this->Users->save($user)`.. this `$user` is the entity.. so I have to use a `$user->toArray()` ?

Comment: @DanielFaria That would be one way, yes. However it should be noted that you might loose extra data that the auth provider has fetched in case configured, for example associations using the `contain` option. So you might want to inject the updated data into the user data retrieved via `AuthComponent::user()`.

Comment: sure.. if you want please add this observation to your answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

In Appcontroller

```
 public function initialize()
{
    ...
    $tableUser=TableRegistry::get("Users");
    $user=$tableUser->get($this->Auth->user('id'));

    $this->set(compact('user','...'));
```

...

In view just use $user['name'] you will get the name. Any update in user will inflect to $user. You can get any fields after update the user with array $user.
I stucked at your case, but i have found the solution long ago. Hope this work. Let me know if it doesn't work. I write out in my memory so it might wrong functions